# Jira JSON date format

Tags: json, angularjs, jira

I am using the Jira API, and need the start and end dates for a sprint.

The JSON data I get back is :

```
{"jodaTimeZoneId":"Europe/Berlin","sprints":[{"id":5,"start":"13082015044305","end":"27082015044305",...
```

Normally, json returns the date in milliseconds, and you need to deserialize that.

Now however, I can clearly see the date (13-08-2015 & 27-08-2015) followed by some other numbers I don't care about. Is there anyway Angular can get the correct format using `| date`? Or any other way I can use?

Comment: see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Yes I have checked that already. Can you do more than provide a link? I have tried | date : 'dd MM yy' but that doenst' help. The problem is (I think) that angular doesn't recognize this as a date.

Comment: then why not create a filter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use `{{13082015044305 | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}` it returns `21-07-2384`. The parsing date format is wrong. So change the format to recognized way.

So I used

```
input.toString().replace(/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d\d\d)/, '$1-$2-$3');
```

Used it in a custom filter.

```
app.filter('correctDateFormat', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.toString().replace(/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d\d\d)/, '$1-$2-$3');
  };
});
```

Then

Display the date as

```
{{13082015044305 | correctDateFormat }}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I was hoping there'd be a build in option, but I guess not. Filter works excellent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
{{ data | filter:options }}
```

where data is your json and date filter

```
{{'1388123412323' | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}
```

an option like this.